# Signal Processing and Emotion Recognition

Tags: speech-recognition, mfcc

I have to write a paper on emotion recognition.
More specifically on how different parameters affect the algorithms effectiveness. I have already read a lot about this and done research using OPENSmlie, (extracting mostly MFCCs) and WEKAs clasificators to get the best results. I use [EMO DB](http://emodb.bilderbar.info/start.html).

However what i need is more theoretical knowledge, and information about already published papers on that subject. Especially newer ones, say from the last couple of years. I want to know, how peaople approach this problem, and how good their latest results are.

I was wondering if maybe there were some experts on that here.
Could you recommend any good recources / links to such papers. Or an effective way of finding the latest ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the latest improvements read the papers from the latest speech conferences, for example here are two tracks on Emotions in latest ICASSP:

[Emotion recognition I](https://www2.securecms.com/ICASSP2017/Papers/PublicSessionIndex3.asp?Sessionid=1169)

[Emotion recognition II](https://www2.securecms.com/ICASSP2017/Papers/PublicSessionIndex3.asp?Sessionid=1154)

You can also check reviews:

[Speech emotion recognition: Features and classification models](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1051200412001133)

[Emotion recognition from speech: a review](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10772-011-9125-1)

[Survey on speech emotion recognition: Features, classification schemes, and databases](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320310004619)

To find the relevant research use [Google Scholar](http://scholar.google.com/).